# runtimeerror: cannot re-initialize cuda in forked subprocess

Tags: django, gunicorn, large-language-model, llama

I have written a Django application which basically load a large language model (`llama2-13b-chat-hf`) with `transformers` (along with `accelerator` and `bitsandbytes`). I have a AWS P3.8xlarge instance and my code is loading the model with `device_map=‘auto’` and with `load_in_4bit=True`.

The purpose of this api is to generate the text for a given prompt as request.

But when I am trying to host this application using gunicorn with the following command - `gunicorn model_api.asgi:application -w 8 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8081 --preload` it is getting loaded. But at the time of inference it is throwing the following error - `runtimeerror: cannot re-initialize cuda in forked subprocess. to use cuda with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method`

If I do not use `--preload` the model is getting loaded multiple times in the GPU memory.

I need help to resolve the issue.